# Visual Studio will not add highlighted text as my search term

Tags: visual-studio

I have previously been able to highlight text in visual studio, and the press ctrl+F, and the highlighted text will automatically be added as my search term.

All of a sudden (I don't recall changing anything), this behaviour is broken. When I highlight text, and press ctrl+F, the search box opens, but remains empty.

I am running visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option that controls that:

"Automatically populate Find What with text from the editor" in `Options` -> `Find and Replace`

[image]