# Find and Replace in Visual Studio 2015 does not take the selected string as default

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In previous versions, whenever I select a text and hit Ctrl + H (Find and Replace), Visual Studio (from now called "it" or "VS") automatically puts the selected text into the Find box.
The problem with VS 2015 is that, the second time I select a text and hit Ctrl + H, the previous text shown in the Find box.

How to replicate the problem:
Step 1: Select an arbitrary text then hit Ctrl + H. The selected text shown in the Find box, which is good.
Step 2: Do whatever and close the Find and Replace boxes.
Step 3: Select a different arbitrary text then hit Ctrl + H. Now the PREVIOUS selected text shown in the Find box instead of the one I just selected.

thanks a lot

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981407/visual-studio-will-not-add-highlighted-text-as-my-search-term

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, I'm sure I have turned on these options. My VS version is update3, Microsoft has no further patches, I suspect it is his fault.